# How to configure SSL for Jenkins?

Tags: ssl, jenkins

We are configuring SSL to work with a couple of our tools, but we struggle to make Jenkins work with SSL.

We have different password for the keystore and the key, hence we need to set both in `JENKINS_ARGS`

By Default, these are the options I found in the /etc/default/jenkins:
 `--javahome=$JAVA_HOME --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT (default 8080; disable with -1) --httpsPort=$HTTP_PORT  --argumentsRealm.passwd.$ADMIN_USER=[password] --argumentsRealm.roles.$ADMIN_USER=admin --webroot=~/.jenkins/war --prefix=$PREFIX`

I searched the documentation [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins), but didn't find anything helpful.

so here are my questions:
1- are there the following attributes as parameters: keyPassword, keyType?
2- if not, what would be the best approach?

Thanks.

Comment: No idea how these parameters will be used in your jobs, but I think you could try to add them in System Settings - `Environment variables`.

Comment: These params must be set for the JVM to understand jenkins is running using SSL, so these are jenkins args that must be set before running jenkins.

Comment: Just to be more precise, I am trying to have a direct SSL access to Jenkins. I think that should work fine if I set a Nginx server between the client and the Jenkins server, but this is not our requirement.

Comment: would this post help? `https://serverfault.com/questions/278555/how-to-use-jenkins-with-ssl-https`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Jenkins forces the usage of reverse-proxy. It doesn't support all the features of SSL to be opened in a direct client-server connection, so I guess using Apache or Nginx reverse proxy is the "correct" way for now.